# Convert string into integers for addition of fractions on C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with converting this input: 1/2 + 3/4 for example. This input is given as string. How can I convert it into integers and do the addition with this fractions. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char input[30];
    cin.getline(input, 30);
    char *tok;

    tok = strtok(input, "+ /");

    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        cout << tok << endl;
        tok = strtok(NULL, "+ /");
    }
return 0;
}
```

I splitted the string and extracted the numbers but they are still a chars, so how can i convert them into ints in that while loop?

Answer (score -2):

Strings containing numbers can be converted to integers using [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).